# How and why does this work?

Tags: html, css, hide, show, show-hide

This guy Motyar from India from the website: http://motyar.blogspot.no/2011/02/handling-onclick-event-with-css.html 
showed a very nice pure css method to hide and show divs. However I can't seem to understand it. Here is the code and please explain this to me, to a newbie.

THE HTML (NOT MY CODE):

```
<div id="lightbox">

              <a href="#">Hide me</a><br />
              Hi!! <br />

              i am the lighbox

</div>

<a href="#lightbox" >Show the lighbox</a>
```

THE CSS (NOT MY CODE):

```
#lightbox {
        display:none;
    }

 /* works with IE8+, Firefox 2+, Safari, Chrome, Opera 10+ */

 #lightbox:target {
         display:block;
      }
```

Please explain this to me comprehensively. Thank you :)

Comment: Rather than restate what someone else has already done: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, the `:target` placed after a CSS token, say for example, `#lightbox` means that the inner code of your rule `#lightbox:target` will be evaluated if and only if the URL of your page is appended with `#lightbox` such as for example, `http://www.stackoverflow.com/#lightbox`. In this case the following code will be evaluated by  the browser :

```
#lightbox:target { display:block; }
```

Comment: Can I give you my explanation on how this works, please correct me because there's this one certain place where I can't get past. 

First the "#lightbox a href text" is show which refers to the div id #lightbox. This has then redirected it to that div, it then makes the "a href text now appear as an "#"". This is where I get stuck. How is this possible, Why does the "a href" change to "#"?

Comment: If you set a `href` attribute in an `a` tag prepended with the `#` character (such as `href='#lightbox'`), your browser will interpret this as a HTML anchor (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3"), allowing you to navigate between elements in a page without refreshing it. This is why your browser does not refresh the page and appends a `#` character to the URL followed by the given id instead.

Comment: Okey I understand mostly now. Unfortunately after some thinking... this would be just a bad way to do what I have been thinking of doing, because I believe there is more work to it than I was hoping for and my original idea for something I was planning on using this for has been changed. Anyway thanks for the explanation :=)

Answer (score 1):

As of  [the W3 Selectors Level 3 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo):

> Example:
>
> p.note:target
>
> This selector represents a p element of class note that is the target element of the referring URI.

So, as you click on `#lightbox`, the `lightbox`-Element becomes the **target** of your URI.

The pseudo-selector can identify this and applies the proper styling.

Answer (score 0):

The key is `:target` pseudo selector. It qualifies to active anchors (`#lightbox` in this case).

You can read more about this here: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/